# Fields getting wiped after one format error

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, allornone

We have a pretty lengthy visualforce page where consultants fill out their account plan. Quite a few fields are of type number -- also date, which is less problematic. If the user fills out 40 fields and happened to enter something other than a number into the corresponding number field, all 40 fields get wiped when they click save due to the refresh. I am looking for some alternatives here. I am using the Database.upsert() with the allornone parameter as false, but that functionality seems to be undefined, with little documentation found online. Also, we do not want to change the number fields to free form text, due to the fact that reporting would be difficult/impossible. I was thinking about using javascript to verify the format of the input. Any suggestions? Input would be appreciated.

save method:

```
public PageReference saveOverride() {
    plan.Opportunity_Name__c = oppId; 
    //upsert plan; 
    Database.upsert(plan, false); 

    for(Integer i = 0; i < ADQR_records.size(); i++) {
        ADQR_records.get(i).Account_Plan__c = plan.Id;
    }
    upsert ADQR_records;

    for(Integer i = 0; i < Persona_records.size(); i++) {
        Persona_records.get(i).Account_Plan__c = plan.Id;
    }
    upsert Persona_records; 

    for(Integer i = 0; i < Carrier_records.size(); i++) {
        Carrier_records.get(i).Account_Plan__c = plan.Id;
    }
    upsert Carrier_records; 

    for(Integer i = 0; i < Theme_records.size(); i++) {
        Theme_records.get(i).Account_Plan__c = plan.Id; 
    }
    upsert Theme_records; 

    PageReference previous = new PageReference('/apex/Account_Plan_Page?value=' + oppId);
    previous.setRedirect(true);
    return previous; 
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any loss of data. Perhaps your controller isn't written well. Some code would help us help you.

Comment: @sfdcfox potsed an update

Comment: Why don't use javascript on the vf page to prevent user entering text on number you can use html5 or use apex:input  or this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AvijitChakraborty. Unfortunately we are using apex:outputField with inline edit, and I don't think that will work in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to always be doing a redirect at the end of the `save` that throws all the data away. If errors are being generated in the `upsert` calls then something like this in the controller:

```
if (ApexPages.getMessages().size() > 0) {
    // Stay on same page and keep the data
    return null;
} else {
    // Go to new page
    PageReference previous = new PageReference('/apex/Account_Plan_Page?value=' + oppId);
    previous.setRedirect(true);
    return previous; 
}
```

and an:

```
<apex:pageMessages/>
```

in the Visualforce should help.

Comment: Wouldn't you add an `id` attribute to the `<apex:pageMessages />` tag so you can rerender?

Comment: Made the changes that @Keith suggested -- seemed logical to me -- unfortunately the data is still being wiped as the page is still reloading/refreshing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was assuming a whole page paint not a part page re-render. But sounds like the problem is something else or a combination of this and something else.

Comment: Actually your solution does work, the user just has to correct the error and then save the page. Only then does the correct value display. If the user gets the error and checks his other changes prior to correcting the format error, he will not see his changes. Interesting..odd.. but it'll have to work for now. Thank you Keith C.